# Always being redirected to /login when using SecurityServiceProvider

Tags: php, symfony1, silex

I have some issues with the SecurityServiceProvider of Silex.

Basically what I want is the following structure:

**/admin/** --> The administration page that is restricted to some users 
(can have multiple suppages e.g. /admin/users and /admin/projects)

**/admin/login** --> The page that visitors can use to login to the 
administration page

**/admin/logout** --> The page visitors see when they logged off from the 
administration page

To implement this, I wrote the following code:

```
<?php 

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; 

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 
$app['debug'] = true; 

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider()); 
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array( 
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views', 
)); 
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider()); 
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider()); 

$app['security.firewalls'] = array( 
        'login' => array( 
        'pattern' => '^/admin/login$' 
    ), 
    'logout' => array( 
        'pattern' => '^/admin/logout$' 
    ), 
    'admin' => array( 
        'pattern' => '^/admin/', 
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/admin/login', 'check_path' 
=> '/admin/login_check'), 
        'users' => array( 
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC 
+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t 
+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='), // PW is foo
        ), 
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout') 
    ), 
); 

$app->get('/admin/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) { 
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html', array( 
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request), 
        'last_username' => $app['session']- 
>get('_security.last_username'), 
    )); 
}); 

$app->get('/admin/logout', function(Request $request) use ($app) { 
    return $app['twig']->render('logout.html', array()); 
}); 

$app->get('/admin/', function () use ($app) { 
    return $app['twig']->render('admin.html', array()); 
}); 

$app->run(); 

?>
```

Now, what happens is that when I visit the page "/admin/" I always get 
redirected to "/login" which is good since I am not authenticated but 
it should be "/admin"login" as the "login_path" parameter in my 
configuration indicates... what am I doing wrong or could this be a 
bug in the SecurityServiceProvider?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing first comes to my mind is that the manual tells you that:

> The login_path path must always be defined outside the secured area (or if it is in the secured area, the anonymous authentication mechanism must be enabled)

See here:
[Silex doc on security with form](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#securing-a-path-with-a-form)

I hope it helps you solve a basic flaw and you can carry on.